# How can I force MS Office 2010's spell check feature to correct misspellings automatically? (not autocorrect)

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-onenote-2010

In Microsoft Office 2010, autocorrect automatically corrects some typos and stuff like that as I type. However, spell check does not. I get a red squiggly line when it detects a misspelling, which is great, but can I make Office automatically correct the misspelling as I type? I know I can right click on the word and choose from the list of corrections, but can I make Office choose the first correction on the list and correct my misspellings/typos automatically?
I would like this feature because I type notes on my computer for my classes, and it would be nice if Microsoft had this feature.

Comment: There used to be an option when you ran a Spell Check with <kbd>F7</kbd> that would do exactly that.  There's a similar button in Word 2010, but you have to press it for every individual word.